# Some exception during recording fields java.lang.RuntimeException: Some exception during recording fields

Tags: java, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I am running the following code in serenity.

```
Response authenticationResponse = SerenityRest.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
                header("Cookie",**Validvalue**).
                queryParam("response_type","code").
                queryParam("state","nothing").
                queryParam("client_id",**Validvalue**).
             queryParam("scope","openid").
                queryParam("redirect_uri","http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Flogin%2Fsuccess").
                get("https://account.tst.com/auth");
```

Running serenity throws a runtime error as shown below,

*Some exception during recording fields
java.lang.RuntimeException: Some exception during recording fields
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.filters.FieldsRecordingFilter.filter(FieldsRecordingFilter.java:52)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)*

Please help me get rid of this error.